# increment one value or another based on mysql column and group results

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have table1(id, name), table2(id [FK to table1.id],user_id,visit).
For each table1.id I need to show its name from table1, count users and show their user_id which belongs to this id and when table2.visit=1, count users and show their user_id which belongs to this id and when table2.visit=0. Also, some id from table1 could be absent in table2, for these ids I want to have 0 in counters.

The result table should look like:

```
id|name|count_visitors|list_of_visitors_id|count_non_visitors|list_of_non_visitors_id|
1 |a   |2             |5,10               |1                 |4                      |
```

Could you help with a query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.name, 
       COALESCE( visitors.visitors_count, 0) AS `count_visitors`,
       COALESCE( visitors.visitors_list, '') AS `list_of_visitors_id`, 
       COALESCE( nonvisitors.nonvisitors_count, 0 ) AS `count_non_visitors`,
       COALESCE( nonvisitors.nonvisitors_list, '') AS `list_of_non_visitors_id`
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT( user_id ) AS visitors_list, COUNT(*) AS visitors_count
    FROM table2
    WHERE visit = 1
    GROUP BY id ) visitors
ON t1.id = visitors.id
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT( user_id ) AS nonvisitors_list, COUNT(*) AS nonvisitors_count
    FROM table2
    WHERE visit = 0
    GROUP BY id ) nonvisitors
ON t1.id = nonvisitors.id
```

Try it yourself: [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80253/1/0)

And if you need it for one user just append one line at the end:

```
WHERE t1.id = 1
```

Comment: excellent. Thank you very much! But my mysql shows NULL in lists, when they are empty and blob when they are not. Could you suggest the reason? old mysql version? now it is 5.1.66

Comment: With COALESCE( sth_that_can_be_null, 0 ) there is no way for any version to show NULL, its what this function does - show first argument that is not NULL. Group_concat may return blob for integers, you can explicitly convert your id's to strings to get a string.

Comment: `convert(COALESCE( visitors.visitors_list, '') using utf8) AS list_of_visitors_id, ` and the same for nonvisitors began to work as in the link above!